# Download attachment of item in list using REST API in SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-list

I have a custom list on sharepointonline, and I have attached a file (myfile.txt) to an item (itemid=5). How can I download this attachment?

I am able download the file with this button:

```
<a type="button" href={'https://mydomain/Lists/Announcements/Attachments/'+this.state.ItemId+'/myfile.txt'} className="btn btn-info" download>Download Attachment</a>
```

I am able to get ItemId with the REST API, but there is no name of attachment files. The only question here is: How do I get the attachment file names like other columns 'Title', 'Created'? I expect 'AttachmentName', but none ofc.

Comment: Can you add some code as to how you formed this url like REST API ?

Comment: Sorry missing that part but your answer already what i am looking for. thanks!

Comment: What is "ofc" (in this context)? ***Original female character***? ***Of course***? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your REST query should be as below:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Announcements')/items?$select=Title,Created,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

In the JSON results, you can get the file name as below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {    
    var item = data.d.results[i];
    var attachmentUrl = item.AttachmentFiles.results[0];
    var fileName = attachmentUrl.FileName;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the post please, AttachmentFiles contains no information about files in response, what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you append `$expand=AttachmentFiles` in the query ?

Comment: Yeah its ok now :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to either use /AttachmentFiles like this

```
{weburl}/_api/web/lists/getByTItle('Announcements')/Items(5)/AttachmentFiles
```

or expand it like this

```
{weburl}/_api/web/lists/getByTItle('Announcements')/Items(5)?$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

The / method only works on single items, where expand works with your OData query